# Disconnect all users in Sockect.io room

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I've been trying to disconnect all users from a room when the administrator wishes.
I can get the sockets IDs from the room but get errors when trying to disconnect or leave the room

This is how I'm connecting:

```
 var io = require('socket.io'),
    http = require('http'),
    server = http.createServer(),
    io = io.listen(server);

    io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
      //socket.join('groupname');
      console.log('User connected');

      socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('User disconnected...');

      })

//This is how the room is connected to
  socket.on('group', function(groupname) {
         socket.join(groupname);
     });

    socket.on('completed', function(groupname) {
         var users = io.nsps["/"].adapter.rooms[groupname]
              console.log(users)
            for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++){
               console.log(users[i])///undefined
           }

      });

  })
```

Have also tried

```
 socket.on('completed', function(groupname) {
       var users = io.nsps["/"].adapter.rooms[groupname]
        Object.keys(users.sockets).forEach( function(socketId){
              console.log(groupname+" client socket Id: " + socketId );
              socketId.disconnect();
            });
      });
```

Any help is appreciated
Roy

Answer (score 8):

Got it done, with special thanks to tienthanh8490, for clarifying managing data within Socket.io

I think what I was doing before, especially with my second example was; trying to fire a function on a string!

Anyway, this works

```
 socket.on('completed', function(groupname) {
        io.of('/').in(groupname).clients(function(error, clients){
         if (error) throw error;
         for(var i=0; i <clients.length; i++){
            io.sockets.connected[clients[i]].disconnect(true)
         }
       });
```

This disconnect all users in a room

Comment: Perfect, worked fine for me with version 2.0.0. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, glad it helped